# KivyMD ProgressBar Thickness

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

How do I resize the thickness of MDProgressBar in KivyMD? I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
MDProgressBar:
    value: 50
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can not change it at the time I post this answer you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/309ce110321d127fab891911d39ba01b5eabc699/kivymd/uix/progressbar/progressbar.kv#L8) is constant and is equal to '4sp' so it impossible

Answer (score 0):

Just a small example with height = dp(48)

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
KV = '''
<home>:
    progression_value:25
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding:dp(24),0,dp(24),0
        Widget:
        
        MDProgressBar:
            value: root.progression_value
            color: 0,0,0,0
            size_hint_y:None
            height:dp(48)                                   
            canvas:
    
                Color:
                    rgba:1,1,0,1
                BorderImage:
                    border: (dp(48), dp(48), dp(48), dp(48))
                    pos: self.x, self.center_y - dp(24)
                    size: self.width, dp(48)
                Color:
                    rgba:1,0,0,1                        
                BorderImage:
                    border: [int(min(self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, dp(48)))] * 4
                    pos: self.x, self.center_y -dp(24)
                    size: self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, dp(48)
    
        Widget:            
''' 
class home(Screen):
    pass

class Test(MDApp): 
    def build(self): 
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(home(name="home"))

        return self.sm
    
Test().run()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGCoi.png)